# How to determine if a URL is pointing to the server itself?

Tags: c++, http, c++14

I have a distributed system that takes in a list of all hosts. The hosts should connect to each other to send/synchronize data. I'd like to keep one simple list of all the hosts and have the hosts ignore the URL that corresponds to themself. Is there an easy way to do this in C++?

Comment: C++ has no concept of networking, URLs,  etc. So you would have to find a library/API that can process the URLs and give you back the IPs they resolve to, and then you can compare that to the IPs of the local machine. But that is not 100% foolproof, as any given URL could resolve to an external IP that routes traffic back to the local machine through networking infrastructure.